# Are there a way to join 2 I/O control lines using staircase two ways switches approach?

Tags: relay, latching-relay, latching

I am a newbie and would like to have a question and would like to have your advice.
Requirements: Control 1 relay (max current is 20mA) over 1 Arduino pin (pinMode as OUTPUT and state of this pin is controlled by the program over Wifi connection) with an additional touch button (TTTP223 module configured with jumper A opened, B connected so that upon touched, the module will locks at maintaining HIGH on I/O pin and upon touching again the I/O pin will maintain LOW on I/O pin). The [TTTP223 module](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/1179637/TTELEC/TTP223.html) is not allowed to use another pin on Arduino or any pin extender board (like PCF8574 I2C).

- When I/O pin of the TTTP223 module is HIGH the voltage rate is 4.2V and drop to 0 in LOW state.
- Arduino output pin is 4.9V at HIGH and -0.6 V at LOW state.

With this requirement, the model will be similar to the use of 2 two-way switches to control [stair case lamp](https://realpars.com/two-way-switching/) (turning Switch 1,2 on/off will toggle the lamp state independently). A sample of circuit is [here](https://www.engineersgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Circuit-Diagram-Flip-Flop-based-Staircase-Switch.gif)
I am thinking of using a mechanism to detect change state on each of the inputs (Input 1 by Arduino and Input 2 by the TTTP223 module) to toggle state of the output. With some searches over the internet, I found Flip/flop and SR latching (and might be the H-Bridge also with the use of a H11AA opto-isolator) circuits that seemingly be of help.
Please advice me with thanks. I hope my explanation is clearer for now. Please be sorry if I would make you be confused (my English is not very good).
Thank you very much for your attention!
It seems that the TS5A3157 can handle well my requirement!
[image: these are the relays that I would like to replace with transistors/iC if posible@]

[image: And here is my final version of the dual control for the DYI SSR relay]. This applied the approach of two-way switches for stair-case lamp.

Comment: You need a lot mores specs on power, impedance ratios, heat loss, mass, acceleration, velocity and position sensing with feedback from current and position feedback with end stops

Comment: Thanks, I have revised the text a bit. Current is very low (Upto 20 mA/4.3-5VDC). The output is just the input for an other pin of the Micro-controller!. Due to limitation on pin, I have to apply this to handle 2 control sources to manipulate the output!:
Example:
I have only one pin (output) on Arduino available but I was asked to install additional physical button to allow control on the output line that will be the input for a relay/Pic

Comment: you are no further ahead than before

Comment: This does not sound like an H Bridge application at all.  Use the edit button to entirely re-state the question by giving a **truth table** of how the result should reflect the two inputs.

Comment: XOR logic gate ?

Comment: Thanks Pete,
I tried many ways and finally came up with the classic solution, mimic the 2-way stair-case with using 2 analog SPDT (TS5A3157) and it work as expected! I will try to go to the next version using the one provided by Swagatam from homemade-circuit. What I do try is to minimise the use of too many part on a small footprint!

Comment: I decided to buy a genuine BTA16-600B from ST with 0.5 USD/PCs and capacitive/ inductive load with almost 800W have no problem at all!
Thinking about resolving cheap Chinese made with protection (additional snubbed circuit as shown in 2nd schematic, work as expected) and/or buying genuine stuff!
Thank you for taking your time!